# Laravel - How to access attribute in whereHas clause?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

My entities are like:

- RequesterType
- Protocol
- Flow
- Document
- DocumenType

The relations are like:

- Protocol belongs to Requester Type.
- Protocol has many flows.
- Flow has many documents.
- Documents belongs to Document Type.
- Document Type belongs to Requester Type.

My needed query:

Select all **Protocols** that has **Documents** in the first **Flow** (let's say with sequence = 1) where has all required **Document Types** for his **Requester Type** (that's actually stored in **Protocol**).

> For example, let's say that I have protocols with requester type 1 and want to check if all document types are present in their documents of first flow. To know all required document types simply query it from protocol requester type.

I started with:

```
$documentsTypesByRequester = DocumentType::groupBy('requester_id')
    ->get();

$protocols = Protocol::whereHas('flows', function ($flows) use ($documentsTypesByRequester) {
    return $flows->where('sequence', 1)
        ->whereHas('documents', function ($documents) use ($documentsTypesByRequester) {
            // Select all documents that has the same
            // requester id of protocol and all document types
            // are present...
            $requesterId = // How to access protocol requester id?
            $documentTypes = $documentsTypesByRequester[$requesterId];
            // ...
        });
});
```

> I need to solve this with Eloquent not with Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to get double duty out of `->whereHas()` which I believe is only a constraint to limit your `flows` to those which have `documents`. Try starting with a `->where()` call that encapsulates all of your matching logic, and use a simple `->whereHas('documents')` and see how that works.

So something like this:

```
$documentsTypesByRequester = DocumentType::groupBy('requester_id')
->get();

$protocols = Protocol::whereHas('flows', function ($flows) use ($documentsTypesByRequester) {
    return $flows->where('sequence', 1)
        ->where('documents', function ($query) use ($documentsTypesByRequester) {
            // Put all of your logic for choosing a document here
            // ...
        })
    ->whereHas('documents');
});
```